# How to create a custom landing page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a landing page which should get display every time when a user enter domain
in to browser and when click on site logo.
How Can I do this ??Please Help

My URL of that custome page is http://boonmodels.com/home.php

Answer (score 0):

create a template page in your theme folder like home.php

```
//home.php
<?php
/**
Template Name: Custom Home
*/
get_header();
get_sidebar();
............ // organize according to your needs
get footer();
?>
```

Then create a page from wp-admin/dashboard choose template "Custom Home".

Then go to Settings-->Reading, choose Front page displays to    A static page (select below) and set your page there. that's it.

Comment: how can i use the default front-page.php as the Post Page